# Google Spreadsheet Filter Column

Tags: javascript, filter, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet within Google Drive that has 5 more spreadsheets feeding information from  a copy of the main `spreadsheet[0]` of the document. I have made filters on each of the other spreadsheets `[1],[2],[3],[4]` in column G with the range `('G1:G1000')` I have a script but is not picking the specific columns in those extra spreadsheets

Thanks for the help!

```
   function onOpen(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var filterMenuEntries = [{name: "filter Column1", functionName: "filter"}];
  ss.addMenu("choose filter", filterMenuEntries);

  }

 function filter(){
//spreadsheet identifier
 var key = '1X7qA--8UxVj37SHON14F4KdrF3DDPpKMtUmhgHVmt51GW4c';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
 var rows = sheet.getDataRange('G1:G1000');// should I set a range here?
 var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
 var values = rows.getValues();

  ss.getActiveSheet();


 for (var i=1; i <=numRows -1; i++){

   var row =values[i];

   // Column value
   var myValue = row[8] //not sure if this is column 'G' or not

   // filter value 
   if (myValue == "DEVPS"){

     sheet.hideRows(i+1);

     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
```

To

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[1];
```

and work with sheet1 (and others) as you wish.